# Matlab, regular expression, load coordinates

Tags: regex, matlab

Suppose the following file containing the polygonal representation of closed areas:

```
1.0   3.5
0.9   -1.4
-4.9  -17.9
0.1   9.6

-9.7   13.3
8.9   11.2
-6.4  0.1
10.3  2.2
```

Each area is represented by the block divided by an empty line. I would like to use a regular expression to load each block to the matrix/array. However, the following code

```
 file= fileread( 'test.txt' ) ;
 bs= regexp( file, '[\n\r]+(*)', 'tokens' ) ;
 bs= [bs{:}] ;
```

provides an empty bs

```
 bs: empty 0 x 0, double
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Define "does not work" - Gives a specific error, matches the wrong values, somehow became sentient and you can't stop it doing laundry...

Comment: What is the intended outcome of the regex? You could split the string with `strsplit(file,'\r\n\r\n')`

Comment: @Wolfie: thanks for your comment, fixed

Comment: `importdata` should work fine in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
bs = cellfun(@str2num, regexp(file,'(\r?\n){2}','split'), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

So you basically split by occurrence of either two newlines (Linux), or two return-newlines (Windows). Each resulting string is converted to a matrix with [`str2num`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html).

A **warning** is in order here: `str2num` calls `eval` internally, so it may run potentially dangeours code. For example, the file can contain `! rm *` and that will be executed. To avoid this, you can check that the file only contains digits, whitespace characters, decimal points and plus/minus signs:

```
valid = all(ismember(file, ['0':'9' 1:32 '.+-']));
```

and proceed only if `valid` is `true`.

The code gives a cell array of matrices, with each block in a cell. For your example file,

```
>> celldisp(bs)
bs{1} =
   1.000000000000000   3.500000000000000
   0.900000000000000  -1.400000000000000
  -4.900000000000000 -17.899999999999999
   0.100000000000000   9.600000000000000
bs{2} =
  -9.699999999999999  13.300000000000001
   8.900000000000000  11.199999999999999
  -6.400000000000000   0.100000000000000
  10.300000000000001   2.200000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to first split the text into the mentioned "blocks".

```
data = strsplit(fileread('test.txt'), '\n\n');

areas = regexp(data, '(-?\d+\.\d+)[ ]+(-?\d+\.\d+)', 'tokens');
```

This would lead to a cell of cells each containing cells of two numbers as strings.

```
{ { {'1.0', '3.5'} ,
    {'0.9', '-1.4'} ,
     ...            } ,
   { ... } }
```

So we need to convert the second stage cells to array of numericals in order to work with them as matrices.

```
areas = cellfun(@str2double, areas, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

... By the way, what was you intension on `(*)` in the search pattern?

Comment: @ Sven: Thanks. However, cellfun(@str2double, areas); leads to: Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1. I set 'UniformOutput' to false. How to convert area to the matrices? (*) was error.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I did not check the code. My bad... I'll edit my answer...